# checkbox Filter divs displayed by class with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this http://jsfiddle.net/RyZy8/221/

The JS

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
        $('#main-div > div > div > div').hide();
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
            $('#main-div > div > div > div[class=' + this.id + ']').show();
        });
    } else {
        $('#main-div > div > div > div').show();

}
});
```

The HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="one">
<input type="checkbox" id="two">
<input type="checkbox" id="three">

<div id="main-div">
<div>
<div>
<div class="one two other classes">
Content
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="main-div">
<div>
<div>
<div class="one three other classes">
Content
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="main-div">
<div>
<div>
<div class="two three other classes">
Content
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The check boxes will filter fine if a single class is used but not when multiple classes are present.

How would I change the following to allow for multiple classes

```
$('#main-div > div > div > div[class=' + this.id + ']').show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to use an attribute selector here since it'll be looking for exact text. You'll want to use the class selector instead, which will just look for the presence of the class, regardless of other classes present.

```
$('#main-div > div > div > div.' + this.id).show();
```

I'd also advise against using nested direct child selectors like you're doing (`div > div > div`). This is quite brittle and will break the moment you change your HTML hierarchy, which will be painful for you when refactoring.

Something like this may be better:

```
$('#main-div .' + this.id).show();
```

Having said that, you also never want to re-use ids on a page. [According to Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id), an id 'must be unique in a document'. If you ever wanted to use `getElementById`, it would only return the first item it finds, rather than an array of items. `main-div` should probably be a class in this case.

Comment: Awesome I think that will work, to clarify, the div using that ID is a single div with all of the others in it, my bad for doing the example the way I did, thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps as important as the refactor is the fact that the second selector will actually perform better, and even better as `$('#main-div').find(' .' + this.id).show();` due to the right to left selector processing in the sizzle engine (which makes the first/nested one much slower) - even though this is really micro optimization on a typical DOM.

Answer (score 0):

See this updated Fiddle; I think it does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/RyZy8/222/.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $('.main > div > div > div').hide();
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i, chkBox) {
            $('.main > div > div .' + $(chkBox).attr('id')).show();
        });
    } else {
        $('#main-div > div > div > div').show();
    }
});
```

You shouldn't have multiple items with the same id so I just changed the divs with id="main-div" to class="main" and put this into the selector within the each loop. I also changed the code to not use the this object (although it produced the correct results), I just used the arguments from the each callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
                if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
                    $('#main-div > div > div > div').hide();
                    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
                        var showId = this.id;
                        $('div.' + showId).show();
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#main-div > div > div > div').show();

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` to create array of checked input `id` and then use `*` contains attr selector to show/hide div with that class.

Also as a side-note you can't have same `id`'s

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  //Create array of checked input ids
  var c = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('id');
  }).get();

  //First show all divs
  $(".one, .two, .three").show();

  //ForEach div that has class as value in array of checked input hide it
  c.forEach(function(e) {
    $('div[class*="' + e + '"]').hide();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="one">
<input type="checkbox" id="two">
<input type="checkbox" id="three">

<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="one two other classess">
        A
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="one three other classess">
        B
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="two three other classess">
        C
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues.

1. You repeat an id in the markup which is invalid HTML and will lead to unexpected issues difficult to debug.
2. After you fix the issue with the duplicate id's you will need to either use a class or wrap them all in some container with an id.
3. You use an attribute selector which is an exact match, change that to use the class selector: (after fixing the id issue and wrapping them all.

Selector code:

```
$('#main-div').find('div').filter('.' + this.id ).show();
```

OR

```
$('#main-div').find('div.' + this.id ).show();
```

I would also suggest you look into the issue of checked/unchecked and the siblings which would determine what should be shown/hidden based on the checked values...I will leave that up to you but it will involve the checkbox change events.  Note that as you have it, all unchecked will show everything, not sure that is your desire.